# Error on connecting to google play services

Tags: android

Hi i'm developing a turn based multiplayer online android app using google play game services. I have configured my app on google developer console according to instructions given in google play game services guide. I also import BasicGameUtils library in me project . But when i try to login to google play services in my app i always get the following error.

**The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.**

Kindly any one know a solution ?.

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appsclubx.project">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.appsclubx.project.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements   
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener 

{

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;
public Button clk,outbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
    clk= (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    clk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    });
    outbtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.out1);
    outbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Main activity oncreate function called");
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Log.d("Error","User is sign in");

}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.d("Error","Google Api client connection on start");
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d("Error =","Google Api client connection on Stop");
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    System.out.println("Google Api client connection failed");

    Log.d("Error",""+connectionResult.getErrorCode()+""+connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // already resolving
        return;
    }
    // if the sign-in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInflow) {
        mAutoStartSignInflow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient,
                connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error));

        // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
        // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
        // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
        // an issue with sign-in, please try again later."
    }
    Log.d("Switch =","Switch to screen");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
            // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
            // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
            // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                    requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
        }
    }
}}
```

This is my gradel build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appsclubx.project"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.4.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0"

compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Authrorize your application to connect to Google Play services. Take help from URL:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth